# Angular subscription only loads on page refresh. Not when navigating between components

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, angular-router

I have an angular app with a dashboard and a few components that can be navigated to with router links.

For example
Dashboard 
Devices

The routing works fine, my only problem is that a subscription in my ngOninit isn't loading when I route between components. it only loads on a page refresh. I've narrowed it down to this piece of code that isn't loading.
THis code is in my device1.componenet.ts

```
 private subs: Subscription[] = [];
  localData: any[] = [];

  constructor(private socketService: SocketService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('onInit');
    this.subs.push(
      this.socketService.getInitialData().subscribe((data: ServerResponse) => {
        this.localData = data.prods;
        console.log('Subbed2');
      })
    );
```

console.log('Subbed2'); shows in the console when I reload the page, but not when I navigate between components.

Any ideas why this subscription isn't working with routing?

The service being subscribed to socket.service.ts

```
export class SocketService {

  constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

  getInitialData() {
    return this.createObserver('initial');
  }


private createObserver(event: string) {
    return this.socket.fromEvent(event);
  }
```

The 2 main components are dashboard and device1. Device 1 displaying the subscription. Dashboard has nothing special just some visuals and a to link to the device components.

device1.componenet.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-devices',
  templateUrl: './device1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device1.component.css']
})
export class Device1Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  devices: Devices[] = [];
  // Devices array from devices.ts
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(DEVICES);
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'serialNo', 'actions'];
  private subs: Subscription[] = [];
  localData: any[] = [];

  constructor(private socketService: SocketService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('onInit');
    this.subs.push(
      this.socketService.getInitialData().subscribe((data: ServerResponse) => {
        this.localData = data.prods;
        console.log('Subbed2');
      })
    );

    this.subs.push(
      this.socketService.getUpdatedData().subscribe((data: ServerResponse) => {
        this.localData = data.prods;
        console.log('Sub2');
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subs.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
  }
}

interface ServerResponse {
  prods: any[];
  type?: string;
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
// Creating routes to components that can be linked to in html files
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: DefaultComponent,
  children: [{path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: 'device1', component: Device1Component},
  ]
},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I'm using a sidebar to handle routing

```
<a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/">Dashboard </a>
<a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/device1">Device1</a>
<a mat-list-item >Notifications </a>
```

Comment: Can you add what part of code is present in ````this.createObserver('initial')```` ?

Comment: Please add the component names, app-routing.module.ts and also how youre routing.  Just need some more information to figure out whats going on.  If the subscription is only firing once that is because youre component is only being initialized once.  So Im assuming theres somthing with how youre routing.  If you were routing between components the component would be destroyed and reinitialized as that is how the page lifecycle works.

Comment: If the 1st code is part of a service, it is because the service is never destroyed, because it is declared as root service, a common mistake.

Comment: does console.log('onInit'); shows the message in console on navigating between components.?

Comment: @DeepuReghunath yes it does. Just not for the "Subbed2"

Comment: @AustinBorn I've updated the question with app-routing.module.ts, the component names and what my router links look like

Comment: Are you sure, that the socket service emits `initial` event multiple time?

Comment: @Akxe That could be the problem. Would you have any advice on how to test that or fix that?

Comment: does this log display "console.log('onInit');"?  If this log does display and the other one doesnt when routing back to it then your subscription might be failing.   In addition the way you are unsubscribing is ok, but please see this article for a better way to unsubscribe. https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an error with the service rather than the component.

Try logging initial data after getting it for the first time:

```
class Device1Component {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.socketService.getInitialData().subscribe((data: ServerResponse) => {
      this.localData = data.prods;
      console.log('true initial');

      this.socketService.getInitialData().subscribe((data: ServerResponse) => {
        console.log('test initial');
      });
    });
  }
}
```

After we knows what this dies, we can follow up

Answer (score -1):

So, the problem in this case was that my server side code was only emitting the table of data on initial connection.

I had a workaround by making a function that is triggered when a component is created:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.socketService.emitSomething();
```

In my socket service:

```
emitSomething(){
    this.socket.emit('something');
}
```

The server upon getting this message send the data:

```
socket.on("something", arg => {
    console.log("eSomething was emitted")
    io.sockets.emit('initial', {prods: [...data]});
});
```

This is probably more of a hack than a working solution. It's quite messy, but I'll tidy it up as I learn more.

Also, I'd like to say thanks to everyone who commented, mostly because even though they weren't an exact answer each helped me debug the route cause and come up with this "hack".